# How to update content of json file present on server using jsch

Tags: java, json, unix, jsch

I have to update the content of JSON file present on the server
I am able to read the file using jsch lib but how to update the content is what I am struggling

```
    sftpSession = jsch.getSession(sftpUser, host, sftpPort);
    jsch.addIdentity(getBundle().getString("config.host.pemfile.location"));
    JSch.setConfig(STRICT_HOSTKEY_CHECKIN_KEY, STRICT_HOSTKEY_CHECKIN_VALUE);
    sftpSession.connect();
    dbChannel = sftpSession.openChannel(CHANNEL_TYPE);
    dbChannel.connect();
    sftp = (ChannelSftp) dbChannel;
```

I am able to read the file from the path specified as below

```
 try {
        InputStream io = TestngListener.sftp.get(path);
        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(io));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I update the values of the file using jsch.
any pointer in this would help.

content of file -

```
{"a": "value1", "b": "value2", "c": "value3"}
```

I need to update the value as per provided keys.

Comment: *I am able to read the file from the path specified as below* so can you parse it using Jackson, edit it, and write it back?

Comment: is there any way I can edit the file using jsch? if not can you pls provide me a sample jackson to start with

Comment: No, and No, search for it, plenty of examples

Comment: then your question should be how to edit a json file, without all this jsch details.